# asp repeater download file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i am creating a website, in asp.net and using C# my problem is i created a asp repeater which is working fine so i added a imagebutton to download the file that the repeater contains, but i cant get it to download that file, hope someone can help me out i have this already, i have tried a couple of ways but could get it to do what i wanted. here is my code.

ASP

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetailsPost" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Save" >
<HeaderTemplate>
<table style="width:500px" align ="center" cellpadding="0" class="rounded_corners" >
<tr style="background-color:Red; color:White">
<td valign="top" bgcolor="CC0000" >
<b>Post</b>
</td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr style="background-color:#333">
<td>
<table style="background-color:#222; width:500px" class="rounded_corners" >
<table>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:large">
Utilizador:
<asp:Label ID="lblSubject0" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("nome_utilizador") %>' 
        Font-Size="small" Font-Bold="true"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#333;Color:White">
<td align="right" >
Criado em:<asp:Label ID="lblDate0"   runat="server" Font-Bold="true" 
        Text='<%#Eval("data") %>'/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table style="background-color:#222; width:500px">
<tr> 
<td>Anexo:
    <asp:Image ImageUrl=<%# string.Format("~/uploads/{0}",Eval("Nome"))%> runat="server"  width=500px/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="background-color:#222; width:500px">
<tr> 



<td>Guardar:
    <asp:ImageButton ID="save" ImageUrl=<%# string.Format("~/imagens/icones/save.png")%> runat="server"  width=30px CommandName="save"
   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Nome") %>' />

        \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\                    this is what I tried   on top     /////////////////

   </tr>
</table>
<table style="background-color:#222; width:500px" align=center>
<tr>
<td>Comentário: <br /><asp:Label ID="lblComment0" Font-Size="small" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("descricao") %>' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  colspan="2"valign="top" bgcolor="CC0000">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
   protected void Save(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Save")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string fName = "teste" ;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fName);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/uploadsadmin/" + fName));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the rendered markup, and what actually happens?

Comment: it wont load the code it doesnt do nohting

Comment: You need to be more specific than that.

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with your problem, but your table markup has a lot of errors. Please revise that. Why do you enclose a Label in a table?

Comment: Please show us more of your code. We need to see when and where you do data binding etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name in `OnItemCommand = "Dwn"` must match the method name in your code-behind.  Rename your Save method to Dwn, or change your markup to match the Save method name.

Refactor the code like this:

```
if(e.CommandName == "Save")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    string fName = row.Cells[2].Text;
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fName);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/uploadsadmin/" + fName));
    Response.End();
}
```

Put your breakpoint on the conditional (if...) and see if the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: thanks tried that too still not working when i click the imagebutton is just refreshes it doesnt enter the code, the breaskpoints arent even triggered

Comment: Edited with another suggestion

Comment: You still haven't followed my first suggestion.  OnItemCommand should be "Save" not "Dwn".

Comment: ok now i edited all of the code as you can see still not hitting the breakpoint

Comment: Only difference I can see is that by default, Repeater.ItemCommand method signature looks for `object source` and not `Object Sender`.  Might be worth trying.  I don't know why you're not hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: I finally got it to work i just added a button outside of the repeater with a dropdownlist with the name of the file, thanks for your help